# How to modify Oracle Database Feature Usage Statistics sample interval time?

Tags: database, oracle

Oracle Database Feature Usage Statistics (DBA_FEATURE_USAGE_STATISTICS) has a field "SAMPLE_INTERVAL" that is 604,800 seconds (7 days) by default. How can this be manually changed to some other number, say 10 seconds or 20 seconds? I need to collect usage updates frequently.

Refer to documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-B8A38B9B-3AAA-4341-AA05-4309870CE73B.htm#REFRN23396

Also, how much performance hit is associated with this? This is for very low load, dev purposes only.

This applies to Oracle Database 12c, but should be the same for 11g and 13c/18.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Totally* unsupported but, did you try:

```
Update wri$_dbu_usage_sample set sample_interval = 600
where dbid = ( SELECT dbid from v$database);
```

as `SYS`?

You may need to manually trigger it to run one time to get it going on the new schedule:

```
alter session set "_SWRF_TEST_ACTION"=53;
```

I haven't tried *any* of this in my database.  Didn't try it, don't want to.

Comment: I was hesitant to run the update query you mentioned, but just running the second one at least forces an immediate run, as you pointed out. That is sufficient for me to help with testing. Thanks.